# Getting an error when trying to run my test in webdriverio

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have been having an issue when trying to run my webdriverio tests after trying to upgrade my node version. I am now getting the following error

```
2022-01-11T12:45:05.628Z DEBUG @wdio/config:utils: Couldn't find ts-node package, no TypeScript compiling
2022-01-11T12:45:05.729Z ERROR @wdio/config:ConfigParser: Failed loading configuration file: /Users/eoincorr/Downloads/coding/DSI_UI_TESTS/wdioTest.conf.js: Cannot find module 'csv-stringify/sync'
```

Can someone please advise me on why this is happening and what to do?

Comment: what is the node version you are using and do you have sync prop in config file set to true?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't install `typescript` and/or `ts-node`.

Install missed dependencies:

```sh
npm i -D typescript ts-node
```

Also make sure, that you have installed all dependencies such as `csv-stringify`